# Determine the class of a non-isomorphic projection of a rational normal scroll as a divisor in a higher dimensional scroll

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group, cones

This is a generalized problem of Theorem 1.1 of [Park's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307001238) and Theorem 1.4 of [Nagel's](https://www.jstor.org/stable/117953). Consider the vector bundle $E=\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then we have the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E)$ embedded in $\mathbb{P}^7$ via the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$, whose image is $4$-dimensional rational normal scroll and given by the vanishing of all $2\times2$-minors of the matrix

$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{10}&x_{20}&x_{30}&x_{40}\\
x_{11}&x_{21}&x_{31}&x_{41}
\end{array}
\right)$

We denote this scroll by $X$. Now consider $p=[c_{10}:c_{11}:c_{20}:c_{21}:c_{30}:c_{31}:c_{40}:c_{41}]$ a generic point not on $X$. I want to consider the projection of $X$ away from $p$. Note that this is not an isomorphic projection due to the dimension reason. But I still hope to follow the algorithm given in Theorem 7.3 of [Brodmann and Schenzel's](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506277). Since $p$ is not on $X$, there is at least one of the $2\times2$-minors of $M$ not vanishing at $p$. Without loss of generality, we assume that it is
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{10}&x_{20}\\
x_{11}&x_{21}
\end{array}
\right)$. In other words, $c_{10}c_{21}\not=c_{20}c_{11}$. Further assume that $c_{11}\not=0$. Apply the coordinate change $y_{11}=x_{11}$, $y_{ij}=x_{ij}-\frac{c_{ij}}{c_{11}}x_{11}$ if $(i,j)\not=(1,1)$, under which $p$ is represented by $[0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0]$. Replace all $x_{ij}$'s in $M$ by $y_{ij}$'s and eliminate $y_{11}$ except from 2 positions(row 2 column 1 and row 1 column 2) by elementary transformations of matrices, for which I omit the details(please refer to Theorem 7.3 of [Brodmann and Schenzel's](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506277) for the technical details). The resulting matrix is

$M'=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
y_{10}&y_{20}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{21}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{11}}y_{10}+
\delta_2y_{11}&L_1&L_2\\
y_{11}&y_{21}&y_{31}-\frac{\delta_3}{\delta_2}y_{21}&y_{41}-\frac{\delta_4}{\delta_2}y_{21}
\end{array}
\right)$

where $\delta_2=\frac{c_{20}}{c_{11}}-\frac{c_{10}c_{21}}{c_{11}^2}$, $\delta_3=\frac{c_{30}}{c_{11}}-\frac{c_{10}c_{31}}{c_{11}^2}$, $\delta_4=\frac{c_{40}}{c_{11}}-\frac{c_{10}c_{41}}{c_{11}^2}$, $L_1=y_{30}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{31}-\frac{c_{31}}{c_{11}}y_{10}-\frac{\delta_3}{\delta_2}(y_{20}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{21}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{11}}y_{10})$ and $L_2=y_{40}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{41}-\frac{c_{41}}{c_{11}}y_{10}-\frac{\delta_4}{\delta_2}(y_{20}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{21}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{11}}y_{10})$.

Then we know that the image $X'$ of $X$ under the projection away from $p$ is contained in the determinant of the matrix

$N=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
y_{30}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{31}-\frac{c_{31}}{c_{11}}y_{10}-\frac{\delta_3}{\delta_2}(y_{20}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{21}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{11}}y_{10})&y_{40}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{41}-\frac{c_{41}}{c_{11}}y_{10}-\frac{\delta_4}{\delta_2}(y_{20}-\frac{c_{10}}{c_{11}}y_{21}-\frac{c_{21}}{c_{11}}y_{10})\\
y_{31}-\frac{\delta_3}{\delta_2}y_{21}&y_{41}-\frac{\delta_4}{\delta_2}y_{21}
\end{array}
\right)$

This defines a hypersurface $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^6$. Hence $Y$ is $5$-dimensional. Now $X'$ is contained in $Y$ and $\dim X'=4$. Hence $X'$ can be seen as a divisor on $Y$. How can we determine the divisor class of $X'$ in $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$?

I know that $Y$ is a cone over a rational normal scroll, whose Picard group is generated by a fiber class $F$ and a hyperplane section class $H$. Therefore I expect that the Picard group of $Y$ is the same. But this needs the condition that $Y$ is nonsingular in codimension $1$, meaning that all local rings $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ of dimension $1$ is regular(Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry II Exercise 6.3). How can this be checked?

Comment: In fact, $Y$ is not factorial, so the class of a (Weil) divisor in $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$ is not defined in general.